# Issue in Angular 8 (After upgrade from angular 4) when we use relative path instated of absolute path

Tags: angular, angular8

I had an angular 4 project with system.config.js.

Now I have migrated a project to angular 8 and also used angular.json/polyfills.ts/tsconfig.app.json (CLI) with system.config.js.

In my angular 4 projects I used absolute path but after migrating it to 8 it gives below error while run ng build command

error in ./app/common/test/test.component.ts module not found error can't resolve  './app/common/test/test.component.html' in ./app/common/test/.

Comment: Are you sure `compoment` and not `component`?

Comment: sorry. it is component. I have updated my question

Comment: make sure your component points to the correct html template path: `@Component ({ ... templateUrl : './test.component.html', ...`

Comment: @Stavm, I have a multiple component and css so I am looking for a general solution. Your answer is correct and previously I tried it and it worked but looking for general solution. Thanks

Comment: can you give us example of how it was previously imported and now what import you want?

Comment: if for some reason you're not able to change paths to relatives, i'd give a shot to changing `tsconfig.json` 's `baseUrl` value from `./` to `~src/` or such, see if it makes things better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Angular toolchain should not rely on the PATH environment variable for finding npm, ng, node, node modules, etc.

The path is limited to 1024 characters in Windows 10 by default and many developer tools, Visual Studio, SQL Server developer, etc. add multiple paths to the PATH environment variable.

Angular under Visual Studio Code requires more strings to be added to the PATH environment variable.

If you run out of space in the PATH variable, Angular paths don't get added which breaks your angular environment.

Suggestion is to make the Angular project self contained with the full set of npm, node, angular, tsc commands and tools in a subdirectory of the project instead of the easy to break common location c:\users\\appdata\roaming\npm.

This has cost me lots of lost hours and given the large number of repeated "can't find ng command" questions on stack overflow many hours to other developers.